# how to use wpf contentstringformat for more than one format?

Tags: wpf, format, tooltip

Is there a way to use ContentStringFormat for more than one format like this in tooltip ?

```
ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N0}{0:P}"

<Slider.ToolTip> <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N0}" /> </Slider.ToolTip>
```

This is how it was. When I change ContentStringFormat like this:

```
ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N0} {0:P}"
```

it shows 505,000.00 % rather than 50 %

Thanks in advance

Comment: we're gonna need more details. What do you want to achieve? What did you try already? What went wrong?

Comment: I want to show tooltips numbers with percentage like 50 %. I want to use {0:P} for showing percentages. But there is also another format used like {0:N0}. If I replace {0:N0} with {0:P}, percentage is shown but the number doesn't look as expected.

Comment: sorry still not enough information - please edit your answer showing what you want the tooltip text to be, and the xaml for the Content - eg if you'd use `Content="{Binding Path=num}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N0} {0:P}"` and num is 0.5, this shows `1 50%` which is correct.

Comment: Thanks for reminding but none of the advices helped me. It is still an open issue. So I can't accept anything that didn't help to solve the issue.

Comment: You would have to either get more precise in your question, or ask us what part of our answers you didn't understand. And you should address us by our names with leading @, e.g. @Clemens for me. Otherwise we won't get notified about your comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems here:

- if it shows 505 instead of 50, the number you input is 5.05 but it should be 0.505
- Second, if you want 0.505 to be displayed as 50% you'll have to round it first
- last, you have to use `P0`

so to round up:

```
//code
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
  }

  private double MyActualNumber
  {
    get { return 0.505; }
  }

  public double Number
  {
    get { return System.Math.Round( 100.0 * MyActualNumber ) / 100.0; }
  }
}

//xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Number}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:P0}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Concatenate "50" and "5,000.00 %" and see what you get.

Comment: what do you mean? if I put `{}{0:N0} {0:P0}` it displays `1 50%`. Not `50 5000.00%`.

Comment: If you look at her XAML you see that she's displaying a Slider value, which by default ranges from 0 to 100. Her example is simply formatting the value 50.0 by `{0:N0} {0:P}`. The result is "50 5,000.00 %". She has either overlooked the space between the two numbers or her format was actually `{0:N0}{0:P}`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the [standard numeric format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) `P` or `p` the displayed number is first multiplied by 100 and then formatted like a floating point number with a trailing percent symbol. A precision specifier right after `P`, e.g. `P2` controls the number of decimal digits. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString).

Therefore formatting a value of `0.5` with format `P2` results in the string "50.00 %":

What you seem to do is to display the value 50 as number (`N0`), followed by a percentage (`P`). The result is the string "50 5,000.00 %" (since the default precision for `P` is 2).